# youtube getting Meta-data of a video

Tags: php, curl, youtube-api

hi i need to print the Title, description and the URL of the FLV stream(not SWF)
the output should be in the form of an XML!!!
i found this code in the web

```
   <?php
function get_youtube($url){

 $youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=". $url ."&format=json";

 $curl = curl_init($youtube);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $return = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return json_decode($return, true);

 }

$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4CRkpBGQzU';

// Display Data 
print_r(get_youtube($url));
?>
```

this code is using cURL to return the details of the video, but i want only a specific information and i cant use JSON how i will can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function json_decode($all_content_request), it return a Class and you can access to items as attributes.

```
function get_youtube($url) {

    $youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" . $url . "&format=json";
    $json =  file_get_contents($youtube);
    return json_decode($json);
}

$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4CRkpBGQzU';

// Display Data 

$json = get_youtube($url);

echo 'List all attributes';

echo '<pre>';//its just to format code

print_r( array_keys(get_object_vars($json)));

echo 'Example use Title : $json->title <br/>';
echo 'Result:'.$json->title;
```

Comment: but in xml how can i do this?

Comment: ok so do you know were can i find all the parameter that i can print with the echo $json...?

Comment: [link](http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4CRkpBGQzU&format=json) no return description data