# Print youtube metadata from $json

Tags: php, json, youtube, metadata

I've adapted the code from [youtube getting Meta-data of a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053317/youtube-getting-meta-data-of-a-video), to be able to print the metadata. It works fine , except the final line is not printing the title.

```
$url = ("PUT A YOUTUBE URL HERE"]);
$youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=".$url."&format=json";
$json =  file_get_contents($youtube);

printf('<br />vid_code is %s', $row["vid_code"]);
printf('<br />vid_url is %s', $row["vid_url"]);
printf('<br />$url is %s', $url);
printf('<br />$youtube is %s', $youtube);
printf('<br />$json is %s', $json);
printf ('<br />Title is: '.$json->title);   //THIS IS THE LINE THAT IS NOT WORKING
```

Seems pretty simple...what am I missing?

Comment: ignore the ] in the $url line....typo

Answer (score 1):

I cannot entirely recognize the approach -> https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json

I would do something like :

```
$url = "OINa46HeWg8"; //some random video
$youtube = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$url.'?v=2&alt=jsonc';
$json = file_get_contents($youtube);

$json = json_decode($json, true);
$title = $json['data']['title'];
echo $title;
```

Outputs :

```
I Forgot My Phone
```

HTML:

```
<h1><? echo $title;?></h1>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<? echo $url;?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Much easier, and no overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to decode the json, use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

**Here is an example:**

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iMR0uac2Kg";
$youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=".urlencode($url)."&format=json";
$json =  json_decode(file_get_contents($youtube));

echo '<pre>'.print_r($json,true).'</pre>';
/*
stdClass Object
(
    [author_name] => Haim Michael
    [version] => 1.0
    [width] => 480
    [type] => video
    [provider_url] => http://www.youtube.com/
    [height] => 270
    [author_url] => http://www.youtube.com/user/lifemichael
    [provider_name] => YouTube
    [thumbnail_width] => 480
    [thumbnail_height] => 360
    [html] => <iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-iMR0uac2Kg?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    [title] => The json_decode Function in PHP
    [thumbnail_url] => http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/-iMR0uac2Kg/hqdefault.jpg
)
*/

//So to get the title:
echo $json->title;
?>
```